# Creating Revision Bars / Markers In Margin Using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a document and I need to track changes using revision bars (black bars in the margin to indicate where changes have taken place).

The changed text is done using `<span class="changeText">.`

Example code, below:

```
<p>This is the original text. This is the original text. This is the original text. This
is the original text. This is the original text. <span class="changeText">This text has
changed. This text has changed. This text has changed.</span> This is the original text.
</p>
```

[image]

I can do this if I treat the changed text like a block, but I need the changes to stay inline. (The image provides the desired sample output).

Any thoughts our input would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use JavaScript to get the height and position of the `.changeText` elements. With this info you can then construct the black bars. Here is an example using jQuery:

```js
var $body = $( 'body' );
var $edit = $( '.edit' );

$edit.each( function ( i, el ) {

  var $el  = $( el );
  var top  = $el.position().top;
 var $bar = $( '<div/>', {
    class: 'edit-bar',
    style:
      'top:' + top + 'px;' + 
      'height:' + $el.height() + 'px;'
  } );
  
  $body.append( $bar );
  
} );
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}

.edit {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.edit-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente cupiditate, eligendi delectus voluptas. Dolore laborum nostrum consectetur incidunt, debitis animi eum vel expedita amet deleniti eaque sed voluptates, consequuntur ut. <span class="edit">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente cupiditate, eligendi delectus voluptas. Dolore laborum nostrum consectetur incidunt, debitis animi eum vel expedita amet deleniti eaque sed voluptates, consequuntur ut.</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente cupiditate, eligendi delectus voluptas. Dolore laborum nostrum consectetur incidunt, debitis animi eum vel expedita amet deleniti eaque sed voluptates, consequuntur ut. 
</p>
<p>
Sapiente cupiditate, eligendi delectus voluptas. Dolore laborum nostrum consectetur incidunt, debitis animi eum vel expedita amet deleniti eaque sed voluptates, consequuntur ut. <span class="edit">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente cupiditate, eligendi delectus voluptas.</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente cupiditate, eligendi delectus voluptas.  
</p>
```

Use [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through the jQuery object of `.changeText` elements. For each find out the height and position of the `.changeText` element with [`height()`](https://api.jquery.com/height/) and [`position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/). Then create the bar element and append it to the page.

Notice that the black bars are absolute positioned. In your final code you may have a container element that you will need to apply `position: relative;` to so the bars appear where you expect them to. Also, I've created a margin with `p` elements for the black bars to be placed. Again, this might change in your final code. You might create this space with the margin or padding of some other element.

Comment: Well done! This is useful.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, you can get an element offset from its parent with the property `offsetTop`, as explained here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop

This, along with the height of the element, recovered using offsetHeight, can be what you need to draw the black markers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

So, for instance, you can use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("changeText").forEach(element => {
  let top = element.offsetTop;
  let height = element.offsetHeight;
  drawMarker(top, height);
}
```

The function `drawMarker` could create divs with absolute positioning using the supplied data, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can mess around with the `:before` css-tag.

I'm not 100% there yet, but this might be a step in the right direction:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gg404keb/2/)

I add a `:before` selector for the spans:

```
.changeText:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  content: " ";
  width: 10px;
  height: 1em;
}
```

Our remaining problem now is that the height of the bar doesn't match with the height of the highlighted text. We can throw some javascript around to solve this.

Last attempt: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gg404keb/5/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight improvement on the JavaScript @hungerstar provided. It regenerates the change bars when the page resizes.

This code uses `changed` and `change-bar` classes instead of `edit` and `edit-bar` classes.

```js
const body = $( 'body' );
const changed = $( '.changed' );

function change_bar() {
  changed.each( function (i, el) {
    var element  = $( el );
    var top_y  = element.position().top;
    var bar = $( "<div/>", {
      class: 'change-bar',
      style: `top: ${ top_y }px;
              height:${ element.height() }px;`
    } );

    body.append( bar );
  } );
}

onresize = (event) => {
  // console.log("Page was resized.");
  $( '.change-bar' ).remove();
  change_bar();
};
change_bar();
```